# How to change the parameter dynamically in pd.DateOffset in python code?

Tags: python, django, pandas

```
date_ranges_values = request.POST['range']    
ft = [df.index[-1] + DateOffset(date_ranges_values = lambda x:x) for x in range(0, 24))]
```

Suppose I get value in `(request.post['range'])` in days, I need to set that particular value in Dateoffset parameter dynamically, But I got an invalid keyword argument for  DateOffset Methods, How do I solve this problem?

sample input

date_ranges_values = request.POST['range']   #(days,months,years)

df  contains

```
 timestamp             state

2016-09-01 07:00:00    423

2016-09-01 07:01:00    298
2016-09-01 07:06:00    251
2016-09-01 07:07:00    466
2016-09-01 07:37:00    415
...                    ...
2016-09-09 04:12:00    284
2016-09-09 04:22:00    322
2016-09-09 04:52:00    287
2016-09-09 04:53:00    441
2016-09-09 05:23:00    365
```

Comment: can you add some sample values for `date_ranges_values` and dataframe df?

Comment: Hi, I can added some sample input

Answer (score 1):

Use keyword args dictionary expansion (**kwargs) to dynamically create the arguments for function calls in Python.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
date_ranges_values = 'days'
x = 6
DateOffset(**{date_ranges_values:x})
```